# Jquery scroll to focused item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollto

I've been searching for an answer for about an hour but I can't find anything that is quite right.

I have a horizontal timeline with icons along it, I've added tabindex to each icon so you can tab through the timeline/icons (they are highlighted using simple :hover and :focus css).

I want to add some jquery that ensures the page scrolls to the currently focused icon, ideal positioning it somewhere close to the center (horizontally) of the users screen and idealy with some sort of smooth scroll...

I've looked at scrollTo but can't find any examples that do what I need.

Please help!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing you're referring to this plugin: https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

in this case you'll need to do something like this:

```
$('.icon').on('focus', function(){
 $.scrollTo($(this), duration, settings )
})
```

duration is the duration of the animation

in settings you'll need to add the offset so that the focused elements is positioned where you want in the viewport

Comment: This isnt working for me, I've done $('.theicon').on('focus', function(){alert('here'); }); and the alert isn't even triggered when I hover or tab on to a div...

Comment: I changed the first line to $('.theicon').focus(function(){ and got it working. What do I passed in to the settings section to get the div in question to sit more or less in the centre of the screen?

Comment: focus is available only on form elements (select, input, etc) and links; you can extend the event to include all elements by adding the tabindex property

Comment: all the parameters are explained here: http://flesler.blogspot.ro/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html basically, you'll need to use offset